# Python(Flask): code changes dont update information on server

Tags: python, flask

I'm newbie in Flask. I'm using stackoverflow for study , and please dont dislike this question a lot and dont take away my ability to ask questions and learn.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

After changing 'Hello World' to any other string the information on server dont changes after runing my new code. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: How are you launching your server? Are you using a WSGI container, or the `flask` command-line tool, or something else?

Comment: just python interpretator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the python dev webserver (calling your script from command line), I would have to ask you if after the change, have you stopped the script and started again. If not, you should try do that.

Another alternative is to do a small change in your script, as in below:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
   return 'Hello World'

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

The debug flag should help your web server to detect changes in the code.

I would also recommend that you go over this tutorial, to help you to decrease the learning curve:
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world

Miguel is a reference on Flask community.

Comment: You're welcome. But if you don't mind, could you post what happens on the output of your web server after you change the string?

Comment: its just printing "Hello World"

Comment: No, I mean on the command line... When you run your script, the first thing it does is to show the URL to access the server, correct? If the debug=True, when you change your .py file, the server will spit out a few more lines, indicating that it has detected the changes... I would like to see this output

Comment: "* Restarting with stat"

Comment: script prints Url if i remove "debug=True"

Comment: Ok. I've just tested the whole process and after I change the string and save the file again, If I refresh my page on the browser, I do see the change on the string.

Comment: my PC is too strange :)

Comment: Can you put your setup and the step by step of what you are doing on your question? I think we are missing something here. Please, go to the detail.

Comment: all what i did is changing app = Flask(__name__) to app = Flask(""somename"), after that i got this problem, thats all

Comment: Ok, so now you are giving a new information. Please do as I've requested, otherwise we'll not be able to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: but after i am runing the old code its dont works, event if i'm closing programm the information stays in localhost

Comment: This is why I want you to edit your question putting all the information. We need to understand what went wrong. But if you prefer to just argue without showing what is going on, it is fine. It's you that will loose a chance to learn more about it.

Comment: oh , i fixed the problem. after each run python programm opened a new task. and first task dont leted to new tasks to update information. after closing all this tasks with task manager the problem been fixed. thank u a lot